# .Net 5 WebApp/WebAPI push and pull to remote docker machine

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, .net-5, pull

I have problem with push and pull .net5 application to docker. I will try show my project structure

```
Solution
   Shared
      Dll1 (.Net Standard 2.1)
      Dll2 (.Net Standard 2.1)
      Dll3 (.Net Standard 2.1)
   Dll4 (.Net Standard 2.1)
   Dll5 (.Net Standard 2.1)
   WebUI (.NET 5)
```

Each dll is used by the WebUI

My production OS is Debian 10.9/11 with latest docker on a separate PC and I works on Windows 10 and VS 2019.

Using change centect I have remote access arrives from my computer (create new contenct on local machine and connect by ssh)

Next step I add Docker Support.. to my **WebUI** - is automatically created `Dockerfile` and `.dockerignore`

everything is fine up to this point

Now I want to publish application to remote docker. Unfortunately already when executing the command

```
docker build -t counter-image -f Dockerfile .
```

I see error message

```
 > [build 12/12] RUN dotnet build "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
#20 0.616 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.0+0538acc04 for .NET
#20 0.616 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
#20 0.616
#20 2.421   Determining projects to restore...
#20 3.849   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
#20 6.869   Dll1 -> /app/build/Dll1.dll
#20 6.923   Dll2 -> /app/build/Dll2.dll
#20 7.019   Dll3 -> /app/build/Dll3.dll
#20 10.30 /src/Dll4/DbContext.cs(20,32): warning CS0114: 'DbContext.UserRoles' hides inherited member 'IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>, IdentityUserRole<string>, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>.UserRoles'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword. [/src/Dll4/Dll4.csproj]
#20 10.56   Dll4 -> /app/build/Dll4.dll
#20 12.27   dll5 -> /app/build/dll5.dll
#20 12.67 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "node" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.67 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec) [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.67 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.67 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.67 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.67 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at TypeScript.Tasks.VsTsc.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.67 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.69
#20 12.69 Build FAILED.
#20 12.69
#20 12.69 /src/Dll4/DbContext.cs(20,32): warning CS0114: 'DbContext.UserRoles' hides inherited member 'IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>, IdentityUserRole<string>, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>.UserRoles'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword. [/src/Dll4/Dll4.csproj]
#20 12.69 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "node" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.69 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec) [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.69 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.69 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.69 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.69 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at TypeScript.Tasks.VsTsc.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.69 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/4.1.4/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
#20 12.69     1 Warning(s)
#20 12.69     1 Error(s)
#20 12.69
#20 12.69 Time Elapsed 00:00:11.99
```

Try:

- Move Dockerfile up from the structure
- Edit path in Dockerfile

everything ends in error
He just wants to run
WebUi on a remote docker as easily as possible

**Update**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebUI/WebUI.csproj", "WebUI/"]
COPY ["Shared/Dll1/Dll1.csproj", "Shared/Dll1/"]
COPY ["Shared/Dll2/Dll2.csproj", "Shared/Dll2/"]
COPY ["Shared/Dll3/Dll3.csproj", "Shared/Dll3/"]
COPY ["Dll4/Dll4.csproj", "Dll4/"]
COPY ["Dll5/Dll5.csproj", "Dll5/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebUI/WebUI.csproj"
COPY . .
#WORKDIR "/src/WebUI"
#RUN dotnet build "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

#FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebUI.dll"]
```

Comment: In this situation I would simply run `ls` in your script to dump out where it thinks the current home directory is, and what it can see there. After some trial and error you should be able to work otu your pathing problem. BTW we really are flying blind if you're not going to post contents of your DockerFile. Also... do you actyually need to build your project inside the docker? can't you build externally?

Comment: I have attached the `dockerfile`.  I don't have to, build locally under W10 works without any problems. However, this is the easiest way I have found to publish application to remote docker server. Among other things, I was helping myself this tutorialhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQSuZFd01tY&t=1583s any easily solution without build on docker?

Comment: Looks like you have a custom build step in your .csproj file that tries to run Node. Can you show the WebUI.csproj file?

Comment: In .csproj I don't have section custom build steps. Following the path @Nick.McDermaid skip docker build in docker. In dockerfile do only publish to remote docker machine from bin\Release\net5.0\publish\ wouldn't it be easier?